# ¿Como usar las tablas INSERTED y DELETED en este Trigger?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Estoy en proceso de volverme loco con esto.
Yo tengo una tabla llamada **Chequeo**.La cual quiero que si hago ya sea *borrar*,*actualizar* o insertar un nuevo registro,este trigger me guarde esos datos en una tabla llamada **Histórico**.

Ahora bien,en esta tabla(**Histórico**)tengo que almacenar datos de otras tablas que están relacionado al cliente que se le hizo un chequeo, mas los datos de la tabla **Chequeo**,todo esos datos los busco con JOIN.

Esta es mi tabla **Chequeo** con datos:

```
 ----------    -------  ---------     -----       ---------     --------
  IdChequeo   IdParte  IdMecanic      Fecha       Matricula    IdAgencia
 ---------    ------   --------       ------      ---------      ---------
     1          2         3       2019-01-15        23000           1
```

y esta es mi tabla **Historico**:

```
  ----------    -------  ---------     -----       ---------     --------
  Agencia     Cliente   Matricula     Fecha       Mecanico      IdAgencia
 ---------    ------   --------       ------      ---------      ---------
 Bella Vista     2       23000       2019-01-15   Juan Perez        1
```

Como dije anteriormente,traigo datos diferentes a la tabla **Chequeo** de otras tablas,pero relacionado al cliente al que se le hizo chequeo.

Aquí esta mi código:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[AuditaTaller] ON [dbo].[Chequeo] 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
Declare @Agencia varchar(50)
Declare  @Cliente  varchar(50)
Declare @Matricula int
Declare @Fecha date
Declare @Mecanico varchar(50)
Declare @IdAgencia int




Declare Datos CURSOR FOR

SELECT  Agencias.Nombre  AS Agencia,
        Cliente.Nombre AS cliente,
        Autos.Matricula,
        Chequeo.Fecha,
        Mecanico.Nombre AS mecanico,
        Agencias.IdAgencia

    FROM Agencias
        INNER JOIN  Cliente ON Agencias.IdAgencia = Cliente.IdAgencia
        INNER JOIN   Autos ON Cliente.IdCliente = Autos.IdCliente
        INNER JOIN  Chequeo ON Autos.Matricula = Chequeo.Matricula
        INNER JOIN  Mecanico ON Chequeo.IdMecanic = Mecanico.IdMecanic



        OPEN Datos
            WHILE 1=1
                BEGIN
                    FETCH NEXT FROM Datos INTO @Agencia,@Cliente,@Matricula,@Fecha,@Mecanico,@IdAgencia
                        IF @@FETCH_STATUS!=0
                            BEGIN
                                BREAK
                            END




                    INSERT INTO Historico (Agencia,Cliente,Matricula,Fecha,Mecanico,[IdAgencia])
                           VALUES(@Agencia,@Cliente,@Matricula,@Fecha,@Mecanico,@IdAgencia)

                END
CLOSE Datos
DEALLOCATE Datos
END
```

Nota:Este código me funciona como esta,pero quiero usar las tablas **INSERTED** y **DELETED**.

Comment: No se entiende muy bien tu pregunta. ¿A qué te refieres con *quiero usar las tablas INSERTED y DELETED*? ¿Dónde las quieres usar, por qué y para qué? .. Tampoco entiendo qué quieres decir con que en `Historico` guardas datos de otras tablas, ¿te refieres a que insertas datos desde otro contexto que no es el `TRIGGER`? ¿?

Comment: @A. Cedano https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: http://chancrovsky.blogspot.com/2014/05/tablas-inserted-deleted-en-triggers.html?m=1

Comment: Si revisas los ejemplos de código de la documentación, puedes referirte a dichas tablas usando los nombres `inserted` y `deleted`.

Comment: Por ejemplo, si la necesitas  para un `JOIN` tendrías que unirla consigo misma, por ejemplo: `...        FROM Agencias
        INNER JOIN  Cliente ON Agencias.IdAgencia = Cliente.IdAgencia
        INNER JOIN   Autos ON Cliente.IdCliente = Autos.IdCliente
        INNER JOIN  Chequeo ON Autos.Matricula = Chequeo.Matricula INNER JOIN inserted ON Chequeo.ID=inserted.ID 
        INNER JOIN  Mecanico ON Chequeo.IdMecanic = Mecanico.IdMecanic` suponiendo que la PK se llame `ID`.

Answer (score 0):

A menos de que la tabla `Historico` tenga una columna para definir la acción, insertar datos de inserted y deleted llega a ser redundante.
Las tablas `inserted` y `deleted` se usan reemplazando la tabla sobre la que se crea el trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[AuditaTaller] ON [dbo].[Chequeo] 
AFTER UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;


INSERT INTO Historico (
    Agencia,
    Cliente,
    Matricula,
    Fecha,
    Mecanico,
    [IdAgencia]
)
SELECT  ag.Nombre  AS Agencia,
        cl.Nombre AS cliente,
        au.Matricula,
        de.Fecha,
        me.Nombre AS mecanico,
        ag.IdAgencia
FROM Agencias ag
INNER JOIN  Cliente  cl ON ag.IdAgencia = cl.IdAgencia
INNER JOIN  Autos    au ON cl.IdCliente = au.IdCliente
INNER JOIN  DELETED  de ON au.Matricula = de.Matricula
INNER JOIN  Mecanico me ON de.IdMecanic = me.IdMecanic

GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[AuditaTaller_Insert] ON [dbo].[Chequeo] 
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;


INSERT INTO Historico (
    Agencia,
    Cliente,
    Matricula,
    Fecha,
    Mecanico,
    [IdAgencia]
)
SELECT  ag.Nombre  AS Agencia,
        cl.Nombre AS cliente,
        au.Matricula,
        in.Fecha,
        me.Nombre AS mecanico,
        ag.IdAgencia
FROM Agencias ag
INNER JOIN  Cliente  cl ON ag.IdAgencia = cl.IdAgencia
INNER JOIN  Autos    au ON cl.IdCliente = au.IdCliente
INNER JOIN  inserted in ON au.Matricula = in.Matricula
INNER JOIN  Mecanico me ON in.IdMecanic = me.IdMecanic

GO
```